# Using Boost ASIO to process TCP without sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp, boost-asio

After following the tutorial on creating [a combined TCP/UDP asynchronous server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime7.html), I'm looking further into applying Boost ASIO to parse data directly from a byte stream.

My objective here is to provide some mechanism independent of sockets. In my scenario, I'm dealing with a file descriptor coming from a Java implementation. In Java, I can read the file descriptor using:

```
is = new FileInputStream(fd);
os = new FileOutputStream(fd);
```

Is it possible to replace sockets with some sort of input and output byte stream and have ASIO take care of processing TCP connections?

Something that came to mind was using `connect` from socket.h; something akin to:

```
connect((int) fd, (struct sockaddr *) &peerAddr, sizeof(peerAddr))
```

This of course sets up a connection and expects a peer `sockaddr_in` to connect to. I was hopeful that there might be some similar way of binding a `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` to a file descriptor. Is something of this nature possible?

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'TCP packet'. There are TCP *segments,* but they are entirely hidden from you. What you get from TCP via the normal APIs is a *byte stream.*

Comment: Perhaps I haven't used the correct terminology. The TCP segments or datagrams are provided through the file descriptor as a stream of bytes. I have no problem reading these out and plugging them into Wireshark. Is it possible to use this file descriptor to read and write TCP in ASIO?

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'TCP datagram' either. It's a byte stream.

Comment: In a sense, although I would describe TCP as a segment structure of a byte stream. When I say "TCP datagram", I'm referring to those parts of the byte stream.

Comment: The only 'parts of the byte stream' that exist are bytes.

Comment: Yes, and those bytes can be interpreted as IP datagrams. If the header so describes, the body of the IP may be expected to contain the TCP datagram. I would like to make this distinction, because other protocols are also active on that byte stream. If it's helpful, I can provide a sample of the raw byte stream.

Comment: If you are using a protocol on top of TCP to extract 'datagrams' from the byte-stream, you should make it clear, else it just confuses experienced network devs like EJP. It's also best to avoid the use of the term 'datagram' when using TCP and/or any protcol based on it, else it sounds too much like UDP. 'Protocol Unit' is often used.

Comment: @MartinJames I see the confusion now, thanks for the clarification. I'm not using (nor am I interested in) any sort of protocol on top of TCP. The byte stream is coming straight from a VPN service and includes all IP traffic, including TCP and UDP.

Comment: @EJP I believe the confusion here is that the TCP segments are in fact *not* hidden from me. The file descriptor from my VPN service provides me with an input stream containing the raw IP traffic. Ideally, I'd like to process the incoming TCP connection, execute some action, and tailor a TCP response back over the same file descriptor. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Moving the comment to an answer, yes boost asio has a facility like this, it's called Socket IOStreams, see here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/networking/iostreams.html

Comment: In that document, the acceptor is still attached to an endpoint using `tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), PORT)`. A brief test seems to show that writing to the stream simply outputs over the socket connection. Is there a way to apply this concept to reading and writing directly to a file descriptor?

Comment: Yes, but it does allow you to abstract the underlying stream (so could be a file stream or socket stream), but your code just works with the base stream classes (such as `istream` and `ostream`)...

Answer (score 2):

Though the Boost Asio documentation contains [what you are looking for](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_streambuf/assign.html), it is hard to find (or even decipher) if you do not already know it is there.

Assuming you have an IPv4 TCP socket file descriptor `fd` from `connect(2)` or `accept(2)`, you can wrap a Boost `iostream` around it with the following:

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream;
stream.rdbuf()->assign(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), dup(fd));
```

Note the duplicated file descriptor, which prevents Boost from helpfully closing your native socket connection out from under you when your stream goes out of scope.

You will probably also want to adjust the backing buffer to fit your needs, as well:

```
char buf[1024]; // or whatever
stream.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buf, sizeof(buf));
```